# convert a string to a directory name

Tags: java, string, file, directory

Here is my case:

```
String dir = "C:/root/dir1/";
for(File f: new File(dir).listFiles()) {

}
```

On executing:

```
System.out.println(new File(dir).isDirectory());
System.out.println(new File(dir));
```

gives

```
false
root/dir1
```

The path stored in the string is valid. On converting the string to file type it looses the separator; how can the directory name be preserved?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can try giving the full name of the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a directory use the following code.   Note the use of .mkdir() method and the double backslash.

In your code I would bet System.out.println(new File(dir).isFile() would return true.

```
 import java.io.File;

 public class MakeDirectory {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("c:\\MyFolder");
    f.mkdir();

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as: *`root/dir1` isn't a directory*.  This might be caused by several reasons:

- The folder doesn't exist.
- It is a file instead of a folder.
- The parental folder isn't correct specified.

Comment: I've checked. None of the three cases listed are true.

Comment: @rookie - What's the complete path the directory?  `c:\root\dir1` or `\\home\root\dir1`?

Comment: It's something like - c:\root\dir1. I've edited the existing question; the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

By doing "root/dir1/" instead of "/root/dir1/" you're going to tell it to look for $pwd/root/dir1, $pwd in java being from the classpath usually, which most likely does not exists.

Comment: I've checked the absolute path and the path; both seem fine. It has something to do with loosing the end separator on converting from string to file. I want to find a way to preserve the end separator.